# error installing PostgreSQL, Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation, error-log

I've been trying install postgres, i try solutions related to WSH,
nothing works to me.

here's the log

```
Log started 01/19/2022 at 21:06:35
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Setting variable whoami from C:\Windows\System32\whoami 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 desktop-5185lk9\franco

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\Windows\System32\icacls "C:\Users\franco}\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_1e0eeb0d2a" /inheritance:r
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 processed file: C:\Users\franco}\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_1e0eeb0d2a
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\Windows\System32\icacls "C:\Users\franco}\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_1e0eeb0d2a" /T /Q /grant "desktop-5185lk9\franco:(OI)(CI)F"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\Windows\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\franco}\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_1e0eeb0d2a\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:
 

Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
[21:06:40] Using branding: PostgreSQL 14
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 SB_Version. Setting variable sb_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 pgAdmin_Version. Setting variable pgadmin_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 CLT_Version. Setting variable clt_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Data Directory. Setting variable server_data_dir to empty value
Executing C:\Users\franco}\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_1e0eeb0d2a/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 "test ok"

Script stderr:
```

Comment: Looks like everything is fine here. If the installation fails, the error messages must be somewhere else.

Comment: The log seems to indicate the installation was successful. Did you check if the Windows service was created?